# Does Barack Obama have an active quora profile?

Tags: politics, barack-obama

A while ago, a friend of mine said that President Obama has just answered a question about the Iran deal on quora.com. I thought then it is just a fake profile claiming to be Obama and giving answers to some questions on Quora. But my friend insisted that it's actually Obama, and sent me a link to that page. I didn't bother to look further and forgot about it afterwards.

Now I have just remembered that and went to see [the link my friend sent me](https://www.quora.com/What-is-it-about-the-Iran-nuclear-deal-that-keeps-them-from-getting-nuclear-weapons). Oddly the link won't open for me and I am facing Error404, but a search on Google says that there was a question about Iran deal, which Obama answered. Was this real? Is it the only answer from Obama on Quora or there are other questions there, which he has answered?

Comment: That link works fine for me.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard This makes it even more odd :o

Comment: If the profile picture is one of Obama, then it MUST be him!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Quora have a [verified profile](https://www.quora.com/What-does-it-mean-to-be-verified-on-Quora-What-are-verified-profiles-How-does-Quora-verify-accounts) system which states

> The verified checkmark icon appears on profile pages for well-known and high-visibility public figures in general interest domains like business, entertainment, government, religion, journalism, sports and other areas.

The profile of [Barack Obama](https://www.quora.com/profile/Barack-Obama) has the quora verified profile checkmark.

You can see from the profile linked above that a total of 6 questions have been answered by this account.

Are they written by Mr Obama himself, or a staffer? That's a question for another day!